# Transfer podcasts

Tags: itunes, automator, podcasts

I just switched from iMac to Macbook Pro and I wanted to transfer all my podcasts to it without downloading them all over again.

Copy/Pasting the podcasts folder won't list it in iTunes.

A found a cranky way to do it by subscribing to the podcasts again, partially download the episode (pause it after a while) and replacing/renaming the full one I have as download.mp4 where the podcast is being downloaded.

This is very cumbersome and I have loads of podcasts.

Is there any way to automate this or can this be accomplished in other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer I was looking for here:

*iTunes: How to move your music to a new computer*
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4527